# Global mouse right button menu with movements for windows

Tags: c++, .net, windows, driver, mouse

I want to create something like plugin or driver for mouse and extend right button mouse menu with movements. First of all, I want to create next feature:

1.user press right button and while button pressed move mouse up 
2.will be shown a simple image with the scheme. arrow up and text "close"
3.when button released current window will be closed.

something similar was in old opera browser and it was very comfortable.

I try to find in googleб but I found how to do only for WPF or browser. I want to create global for the whole system with different configs. for example mouse, up in explorer will close the window and in visual studio, it will fire "Run"(f5). 
I want to create this using C#. also I have basic knowledge in c++.
I will be grateful for help

Comment: Why is this tagged then with C++ ?

Comment: If this can only be done at the driver level, then I'll have to write in with c++. And since it does not stop me, I want to know a more optimal solution for my task.